# How to get utf-8 in json_encode php when convert from array to string?

Tags: php, jsonencoder

How to get `utf-8` in `json_encode` php when convert from array to string ?

This is my code for `test.php`:

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<?PHP
session_start();
include("connect.php");
$word = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_mysqli,$_GET['word']);
$xx = array();
$xx[] = $word;
$xx[] = $word;
$xx_1 = json_encode($xx);
print_r($xx_1);
?>
```

When test load

```
example.com/test.php?word=神州
```

It's show

```
["\u795e\u5dde","\u795e\u5dde"]
```

I want to show like this

```
["神州","神州"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$xx_1 = json_encode($xx, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
print_r($xx_1);.
```

works for php5.4+

Actually `["\u795e\u5dde"]` is same as `["神州"]`. most of the time you `json_encode` the data before storing/transferring data around and after that you have to `json_decode` the value and process it, the `json_docode` will take care of the unicodification. But the above code should give you what you needed.

[Doc Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: With this code it's not show anything `$xx_1 = json_encode($xx, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
print_r($xx_1);.`

Comment: i don't know why its like this in your case, but when i tried it my console `>>>json_encode(['神州'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
=> "["神州"]"` the proper output came

Comment: it shows nothing means the array itself might be empty

Comment: `<meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<?PHP
session_start();
include("connect.php");
$word = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_mysqli,$_GET['word']);
$xx = array();
$xx[] = $word;
$xx[] = $word;
//$xx_1 = json_encode($xx);
$xx_1 = json_encode($xx, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
print_r($xx_1);
?>`

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

```
$db_mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```